# Am I calling this API correctly for HaveIBeenPwned (HIBP)?

Tags: javascript, api, postman

I am fairly new to web development and using API's, and for some reason I keep getting a 401 "Access denied due to missing hibp-api-key." error when trying to use this one API for the website HaveIBeenPwned. I'm using Postman just to check the API, and here is what I am using: https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/pasteaccount/foo%40bar.com%20hibp-api-key:%20XXXXXXXXXXXX #API Key was redacted at the end, and the email is a test email.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and why it keeps giving me an error? I've checked my API key a million times and I just don't know why this isn't working! Here is the documentation: https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3
It says:

> The API takes a single parameter which is the email address to be
> searched for. The email is not case sensitive and will be trimmed of
> leading or trailing white spaces. The email should always be URL
> encoded. This is an authenticated API and an HIBP API key must be
> passed with the request.
>
> GET [https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/pasteaccount/{account}](https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/pasteaccount/%7Baccount%7D)
> hibp-api-key: [your key]

Comment: Based on the docs, `hibp-api-key` should be passed as a HTTP header, not in the URL.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you so much! I'm still super new to this, so I didn't even realise it stated that

Answer (score 0):

The key needs to be passed in the header per the docs here: https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#Authorisation

> The key is then passed in a "hibp-api-key" header:

```
GET https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/{service}/{parameter}
hibp-api-key: [your key]
```